# Is there a radix function in ruby?

Tags: ruby

While reading through another question here, on creating a URL shortening service, it was suggested to take the ID of the row, and then convert it to base 62 (0 to 9, a to z, and A to Z).  Is there a standard function to accomplish this in Ruby?

Edit:
Not sure if I was clear enough.

Something like this:
123456.radix(62)

should give the base 62 of 123456.

I'm thinking of writing one, if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001069) method in Ruby integer classes has an optional parameter specifying the base, something like:

```
123456.to_s(16)
```

However, it only accepts values from 2 to 36 as the radix.

[This snippet](http://refactormycode.com/codes/125-base-62-encoding) might be a good starting place if you want to write your own encoder. There's also a [base62 Ruby Gem](http://base62.rubyforge.org/) that adds methods for encoding and decoding in base62.

Answer (score 5):

Since I recently needed to use radixes in Ruby, and since this is the first result for 'Ruby radix', I thought I would point out that there is now [a gem](http://rubyworks.github.com/radix/) for working with radixes.  Here is how to code the OP's example using it:<sup>1</sup>

```
require 'radix'
SIXTYTWO = ('0'..'9').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
123456.b(62).to_s(SIXTYTWO)
```

<sup>1</sup> The `SIXTYTWO` array is needed because the gem doesn't make any assumptions about which characters to use to encode the result.

Answer (score 0):

Could not open links for base62 encoding gem, and also doesn't like fuctionality of radix gem. SO found this one fast and simple solution for base62 encodings:

https://github.com/steventen/base62-rb